# What XMPP clients currently support PubSub (XEP-0060)?

Tags: xmpp

What end-user clients (not libraries) expose [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) [XEP-0060](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe#See_also) to users right now?

Answer (score 2):

[tkabber](http://tkabber.jabber.ru)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Tkabber, but there are various clients that'll let you play with PubSub. None of them exposes innovative user interfaces that leverages the unique concepts of PubSub : they are mostly developer tools for basic CRUD in the service discovery node tree. But maybe this is just what you need...

Instant messaging clients with PubSub service discovery :

- [Miranda](http://www.flickr.com/photos/pip/2548390542/)
- [Psi](http://www.process-one.net/images/uploads/xmpp_app_server1.jpg)

Specialized PubSub administration clients :

- [PubSubClient](http://seriously-this-is-not-worth-reading.blogspot.com/2009/01/pubsubclient-back-in-development.html)
- [x60br](http://x60br.berlios.de/)